# Request header field X-CSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: laravel, cors

I had a laravel project, when I run **php artisan serve**, there shows an error in browser:

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/news/get-news-list: Request header field X-CSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

my code is like following:

```
axios.get(domainName+'/api/news/get-news-list').then(response=>{
    news = response.data.list;
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And I already add middleware like following:

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
];
```

**Cors.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type,Authorization');

}
```

**api.php**

```
Route::prefix('news')->group(function () {
    Route::get('get-news-list', 'API\NewsController@getList')->middleware('cors');
});
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add `x-csrf-token` header to allowed list. In your case, it's in `Cors.php` file, header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` controls what headers are allowed in CORS request.

Comment: I add 'Content-Type,Authorization, X-Requested-With,X-CSRF-Token' in Access-Control-Allow-Headers, then it works, thanks man!

Comment: I am facing problem to add it, can you guys help me?